# how reference article in bibtex format of springer journal

Tags: bibtex

I want to reference the article in BibTeX as follows:

Slifka MK, Whitton JL (2000) Clinical implications of dysregulated cytokine production. J Mol Med. https://doi.org/10.1007/s001090000086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Springer LaTeX Template, take `sn-basic.bst` style, and copy it to the same folder where your LaTeX file is loacated. Then use it in the following way:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{my.bib}
@article{Slifka:2000,
  author = {Mark K. Slifka and J. Lindsay Whitton},
  title = {Clinical implications of dysregulated cytokine production},
  journal = {Journal of Molecular Medicine},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {78},
  number = {2},
  pages = {74--80},
  doi = {10.1007/s001090000086},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\def\bibcommenthead{}
\begin{document}
This is a citation: \cite{Slifka:2000}.
\bibliographystyle{sn-basic}
\bibliography{my.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to reference citations in the text identified by numbers in square brackets. how can I do that?

Comment: @u1997, "For use with the natbib package (see below). Default is author-year citations. When citations are numbered, please use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`." - taken from `sn-basic.bst` file.